# Accessibilty about Protected Member

Tags: c#, oop, protected

I have read all over the internet and books that `protected` member can be accessed within the class only and in the derived class only. I am experimenting with following code

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
abstract class A
{
    protected int n_IntA = 0;
    public abstract void AMethod();
}
abstract class B : A
{
    int nb;
    public B()
    {

    }
    public abstract void GetProtected();      
    public override void AMethod()
    {

    }
}
class C : B
{
    public override void GetProtected()
    {
        // Here n_IntA is accessible why ??
    }
}
```

But here in class c `n_IntA` is accesible. Why? Derive class for `A` is `B`.So accessibility of `n_IntA` must be upto the class B only ??

Comment: Because C inherits from B that inherits from A.

Comment: @Belogix that means this member will be accessible to all those classes who maintain this chain of inheritance

Comment: That is right, everything inherits from `System.Object` no matter how many things are on top of that. Unless you hide (using `new`) then the items bubble up if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessibility goes through *ALL* of the inheritance-tree.

If you are no explicitly hiding a member, for example using `new`-operator, you can access These members far down the inheritance tree.
Take a look at MSDN and see how deep inheritance goes especially in the WinForms and WPF-classes. If you couldn't access members defined in `System.Object` the entire framework would break...

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx):

> Use the access modifiers, public, protected, internal, or private, to specify one of the following declared accessibility levels for members.
>
> ...
> protected | Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.

Answer (score 2):

Protected members are always accessible from the derived class no matter what is the level of hierarchy. here in question `n_IntA`  is accessible because

C inherits from B that inherits from A

also you did not modified the specifier in class B it remains protected in B and same thing happens for C